# Organize imports with Maven2, Eclipse-style?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm a lone Emacs user in a group that's hung up on Eclipse. Time and again, code diffs are made larger by imports that have been "organized" or "cleaned up" by Eclipse.

I don't have a strong opinion on the subject of import style in Java, but I do want to minimize our diffs. What can I do?

We use Maven2 for builds; is there a plugin that can help me? Can a piece of Eclipse be abstracted out & turned into a Maven plugin? I currently use [ImportScrubber](http://importscrubber.sf.net/) and have encountered a few other stand-alone pieces that do the same thing. What I'm really looking for is a Maven plugin that can integrate with the build.

Barring the above, I'll put an ImportScrubber invocation into my `.git/hooks/post-commit`.

Comment: Note that one of the things that Eclipse does, is to resolve imports to the individual class so e.g. "Date" is never ambigous.

Comment: Try this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/46679149/95073

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Hybridlabs](http://www.hybridlabs.org/) beautifier which is used internally in the [openArchitectureWare](http://www.openarchitectureware.org/) project (an open source generator framework) is doing what you're looking for. As explained in this [blog entry](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/category/software-development/open-source/hybridlabs-beautifier/), the beautifier is available as a [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/hybridlabs-beautifier) and its [documentation](http://www.hybridlabs.org/data/hybridlabs-beautifier.pdf) describes a maven 2 plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hybridlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-beautifier-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
         <execution>
             <goals>
                 <goal>beautify-imports</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
    <configuration>
         <!-- Recursively scan for *.java and beautifies imports -->
         <inputDirectory>${pom.basedir}/..</inputDirectory>
         <!--outputDirectory>${pom.basedir}/..</outputDirectory>
         <runBeautifier>true/runBeautifier>
         <runJalopy>false</runJalopy-->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There is indeed a mojo in the [source tree](http://code.google.com/p/hybridlabs-beautifier/source/browse/#svn/trunk/hybridlabs-beautifier/src/main/java/org/hybridlabs/source/formatter/m2) but it doesn't match the `groupId` mentioned above (this is a bit confusing) and I've not been able to find the plugin in maven's public repository.

Maybe you'll be more lucky with the version available in AndroMDA plugin repository as documented in [this thread](http://galaxy.andromda.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6486&sid=32e1558ebf1c1ecbfbe62a123fe8c2cb) (the plugin is indeed present in http://team.andromda.org/maven2/).

> The plugin is under
>   `org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-beautifier-plugin`.
>   It can be run with the short form:
>   `mvn beautifier:beautify-imports`. It
>   can also be run as part of a project
>   pom by adding the plugin declaration
>   under `<build><plugins>`:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-beautifier-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0</version>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>beautify-imports</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
>     <configuration>
>         <inputDirectory>${pom.basedir}/target/src</inputDirectory>
>     </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

Or contact the project's author (e.g. through [twitter](http://twitter.com/kthoms)  or by mail).

Comment: I think this plugin is now available as org.andromda.maven.plugins:andromda-beautifier-plugin:3.4 on Maven central. Its purpose is to convert fully qualified class names in code into import statements, not to clean up existing import statements. Having tried it on my code, it appears to do nothing at all!

Answer (score 2):

I think all of you (Eclipse, Emacs or whatever users) should use something like Jalopy which supports both [Eclipse](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/jalopy-eclipse/index.html) and [Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jalopy-maven-plugin/howto.html). This way it becomes irrelevant where the code was modified as long as it has been run through pretty-printer as part of checking code in. Said that - I'm not sure if Jalopy supports organizing imports beyond sorting these up

Comment: Jalopy is very good, I bought a license for it. Unfortunately everyone else is to mean to fork out the 20 euros, so I can only use it on projects that I alone work on...

Answer (score 1):

I have also found an [ImportScrubber plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/maven/maven-importscrubber-plugin). Can't as of yet attest to its quality.

Comment: That import scrubber plugin looks like a hangover from Maven 1. I'm not totally sure, but there is jelly involved.

Comment: Looked into this some more. IT requires the files to be compiled first, and works out what the imports should be from the .class files. It also has some limitations, like if you static import a constant, but do not otherwise use the class containing the constant, it will get removed and break your code. Its also quite old, will it even work with Java 5, 6, 7, 8?

Answer (score 0):

Does your shop have code standards for how imports should be organized?  If so then you are out of luck.  Minimizing diffs is a small sacrifice to make towards incremental code improvement.

Comment: We have no standards other than "make sure it works". :) Seriously though, we can't even get past the "Windows/Unix line endings" inconvenience. Those of us who are privy to `diff -b` don't care.